# SQL Test Question need help using subselect

Tags: mysql, sql

The question is : "which are the countries with a head of state which is the head of state of at least 2 countries"

and this is how the table looks

| Country |
| --- |
| Name |
| Headofstate |

This is what I've tried so far but it only gives back countries with a headofstate count of 1

```
Select name, count(headofstate)
from country
where exists(select headofstate, count(name) from country group by headofstate having count(name) >= 2)
group by name
```

The expected result should be countries with a head of state which is the head of state of at least 2 countries but what I'm getting is countries with a headofstate count of 1

Comment: Add table as text and what you have tried so far

Comment: So far I tried this: 

Select name, count(headofstate)
from country
where exists(select headofstate, count(name) from country group by headofstate having count(name) >= 2)
group by name

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: please add it to your question using the edit function not as comment

Comment: And now we need sample data, expected result and result you get

Comment: Done! I'm sorry as this is my first time using stackoverflow 

Comment: "Done" - no. You haven't shared the table structure, not sample input data, nor the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery needs to be correlated with the main query, by matching the `headofstate` columns.

```
Select name
from country AS c1
where exists(
    select *
    from country AS c2
    WHERE c1.headofstate = c2.headofstate
    group by headofstate 
    having count(name) >= 2
)
```

There's no need for grouping in the main query. Each country only appears once in the `country` table.

When you use a query in `EXISTS()` you don't have to specify any columns to select, since it just tests whether the row exists, not the values.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be the withdrawal of the head of state and the list of countries where he is the head of state

```sql
SELECT Headofstate, count(*) AS c, GROUP_CONCAT(Name)
FROM Country
GROUP BY Headofstate
HAVING c >= 2
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it